# Gradle - attach info to a dependency

Tags: gradle

I have some dependencies declared:

```
runtime 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
runtime 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2'
runtime 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

I have a copy dependencies task:

```
task copyRuntimeLibs(type: Copy) {
  into "build/dependencies"
  from configurations.runtime
}
```

I would like to be able to "mark" some dependencies in order to route them later in the copyRuntimeLibs in different folders. Something like:

```
runtime 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2' { subdir='dir1' }
runtime 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2' { subdir='dir2' }
runtime 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2' { subdir='dir3' }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple custom configurations, which then all contribute towards runtime:

```
configurations{
    subRun1
    subRun2
    subRun3
    runtime.extendsFrom(subRun1, subRun2, subRun3)
}
```

In your copy tasks, you can copy from each subconfiguration into their respective folders:

```
task copySubRun1Libs(type: Copy) {
  into "build/dependencies/dir1"
  from configurations.subRun1
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought too but I hoped there were a shorter way than defining 1 config per custom behavior. If I wanted to attach a second piece of information to my dependency it would make it pretty cumbersome.